# Extra argument 'error' in call - swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift2

Upgrading my test app to swift 2.

```
      private func parsePeopleFromData(peopleData : NSData) -> [Person] {
            var people = [Person]()
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(peopleData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error : nil) as! NSDictionary
            if let rawPeople = rawPeopleDataFromJSON(jsonResult) {
                people = parsePeopleFromRaw(rawPeople)
            }
            return people
        }
```

It shows error on the following line, specifically on **error : nil**

```
let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(peopleData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error : nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Help me to fix the issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use "Convert to latest Swift Syntax". It converts the syntax to the new error handling. It's also described in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: After the conversion, still showing the same error. Can you post the updated code, since i am very new to swift and iOS coding.